# Problema com uso de Service Worker(A ServiceWorker passed a promise to FetchEvent.respondWith() that resolved with non-Response value 'undefined'.)

Tags: javascript, service-worker

A service worker que vou mostrar abaixo funciona bem no google chrome, porem quando estou usando o mozila firefoz retorna o erro:

```
Failed to load 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/#/'. A ServiceWorker passed a promise to FetchEvent.respondWith() that resolved with non-Response value 'undefined'.
```

Desta forma fico com meu site limitado ao chrome. Gostaria de ajuda para poder ter o publico do firefox tambem. Tó usando localmente para teste da service worker, por isto está 127.0.0.1:8000.

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", function(e) {
  const url = new URL(e.request.url);
  if (
    url.hostname === "https://meu.site.com" ||
    url.hostname === "cdnjs.cloudflare.com" ||
    url.hostname === "fonts.googleapis.com" ||
    url.hostname === "https://meu.site.homologacao.com/"
  ) {
    e.respondWith(
      caches.match(e.request).then(function(response) {
        var fetchRequest = e.request.clone();
        return fetch(fetchRequest)
          .then(function(response) {
            if (
              response ||
              response.status === 200 ||
              response.type === "basic"
            ) {
              console.log("OnLine");
              return response;
            } else {
              console.log("OffLine");
              var responseToCache = response.clone();
              caches.open(STATIC_CACHE_NAME).then(function(cache) {
                cache.put(e.request, responseToCache);
              });
              return response;
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log("Fetch failed; returning offline page instead.", error);
            return caches.match(OFFLINE_URL);
          });
      })
    );
  } else if (CACHE_APP.indexOf(url.pathname) !== -1) {
    e.respondWith(caches.match(e.request));
  }
});
```

Alguem poderia me ajudar com este erro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desculpe. Solucionei o problema adicionando a url do 127.0.0.1
Ficou assim:

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", function(e) {
  const url = new URL(e.request.url);
  if (
    url.hostname === "https://meu.site.com" ||
    url.hostname === "cdnjs.cloudflare.com" ||
    url.hostname === "fonts.googleapis.com" ||
    url.hostname === "https://meu.site.homologacao.com/"
  ) {
    e.respondWith(
      caches.match(e.request).then(function(response) {
        var fetchRequest = e.request.clone();
        return fetch(fetchRequest)
          .then(function(response) {
            if (
              response ||
              response.status === 200 ||
              response.type === "basic"
            ) {
              console.log("OnLine");
              return response;
            } else {
              console.log("OffLine");
              var responseToCache = response.clone();
              caches.open(STATIC_CACHE_NAME).then(function(cache) {
                cache.put(e.request, responseToCache);
              });
              return response;
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log("Fetch failed; returning offline page instead.", error);
            return caches.match(OFFLINE_URL);
          });
      })
    );
  } else if (CACHE_APP.indexOf(url.pathname) !== -1) {
    e.respondWith(caches.match(e.request));
  }
});
```